# Sql transaction error occurs sometimes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

I am writing c# software which uses mssql2008r2 database. My software runs on many computers at same time. But sometimes mssql throws an error "new transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session".

I believe that the transaction on one connection is not relevant to the other transactions on other connections. I don't need to know whether there are other active transactions on other connections to start a transaction, is that right?

Please give me an advice!

Regards,
Orgil.D

Comment: `because there are other threads running in the session` makes me think maybe one query takes long and before its done, another one is fired.

Comment: But if that query is on other connection, my connection doesn't care about that query, is that right?